# How can i distinguish between rejection vs the base transaction in the safe-transaction service

Tags: gnosis-safe

If I create a safe transaction and post it to the safe transaction service, then create a rejection, gnosis generates another safeTxHash with the same nonce. How can I determine which one is the rejection transaction, which one is the approval transaction?

Am I understanding this correctly? How does the Gnosis UI distinguish this?

Answer (score 0):

The rejection transaction will have empty `data`, zero `value`, zero `safeTxGas` and `to` will be the Safe address